# Java multithreading lock is not working correctly

Tags: java, multithreading

The whole program is :

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

public class AccountWithConditionsUser {
    private static Account account = new Account();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Thread 1\t\tThread 2\t\tBalance");
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        executor.execute(new DepositTask());
        executor.execute(new WithdrawTask());
        executor.shutdown();
        while(!executor.isShutdown()) {
        }
    }
    public static class DepositTask implements Runnable{
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true) {
                    account.deposit((int)(Math.random()* 10)+ 1);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static class WithdrawTask implements Runnable{
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                account.withdraw((int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private static class Account{
        private static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
        private static Condition newDeposit = lock.newCondition();
        
        private int balance = 0;
        public int getBalance() {
            return balance;
        }
        
        public void withdraw(int amount) {
            lock.lock();
            System.out.println("->Withdraw Obtained Lock");
            try {
                while(balance < amount) {
                    System.out.println("\t\t\tWait for deposit");
                    newDeposit.await();
                }
                balance-=amount;
                System.out.println("\t\t\tWithdraw "+ amount + "\t\t" + getBalance());
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                System.out.println("->Withdraw Released Lock");
                lock.unlock();
                
            }
            
        }
        
        public void deposit(int amount) {
            lock.lock();
            System.out.println("->Deposit Obtained Lock");
            try {
                balance+=amount;
                System.out.println("Deposit "+ amount + "\t\t\t\t\t" + getBalance());
                newDeposit.signalAll();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                System.out.println("->Deposit Released Lock");
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the sample part of the output I got for this code is:

......

......

Withdraw Released Lock

Withdraw Obtained Lock

Wait for deposit

Deposit Obtained Lock

Deposit 9                   13

Deposit Released Lock

Withdraw 9      4

Withdraw Released Lock

.....

.....

The question here is how Deposit thread obtained lock after window obtained lock. Isn't it supposed to be that once a lock is obtained it can't be obtained by any other thread! Or is it because of the signal methods? Can anyone please explain how that output came?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `Withdraw` obtains the lock it checks if there is sufficient balance. If there is not, then it calls `newdeposit.await`, which will release the lock so other threads waiting on the same lock can get in. That appears to be what happened: `Withdraw` entered into that if-block, started waiting, the `Deposit` thread came in and deposited an amount and woke `Withdraw` up, so it can continue with the updated amount. Once a notification is received, `await` locks and returns, so `Withdraw` continues execution with lock acquired.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Just wanted to make sure... So if `newDeposit.await` releases the lock and once `Withdraw` obtains the lock what does `newDeposit.signal` do....does it also release the lock obtained by deposit and gives it to withdraw back (If so the rest of the code in withdraw shouldn't been executed right like the print statement in finally block) or it does something else.?

Comment: @Badri, Note that `await()` doesn't _simply_ release the lock. It releases the lock, it awaits the notification, and then it waits (if necessary) to _re-acquire_ the lock. The lock will always be re-locked before `await()` returns.